How to Set Default Values for Only the First Instance of a Repeater in Filament Forms?
I'm working with a Filament form that includes a repeater component, and I want to set default values only for the first instance of the repeater based on some values from outside the repeater. However, my current implementation sets default values for all instances instead of just the first one.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
Wizard\Step::make('पारिवारिक व्यक्तिगत विवरण')
                        ->schema([
                            Repeater::make('family_details')
                            ->label('पारिवारिक व्यक्तिगत विवरण')
                            ->schema([
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                    ->label('नाम, थर')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(255)
                                    ->default(function (Get $get) {
                                        // Pre-fill with household head name
                                        return $get('../../household_head');
                                    }),

                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('age')
                                    ->label('उमेर')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->numeric()
                                    ->default(function (Get $get) {
                                        // Pre-fill with household head age
                                        return $get('../../age');
                                    }),
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('gender_id')
                                    ->label('लिंग')
                                    ->options(\App\Models\Gender::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                                    ->nullable(),
                                 
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('contact_number')
                                    ->label('संपर्क नं.')
                                    ->maxLength(10)
                                    ->numeric()
                                    ->default(function (Get $get) {
                                        // Pre-fill with household head contact number
                                        return $get('../../contact_number');
                                    }),
                            ])
                            ->columns(3) // Adjust the number of columns as needed
                            ->maxItems(fn (Get $get) => $get('total_family_count')-0 ?? 0)
                            ->defaultItems(1),
                        ]),

I try:
->default(function (Get $get, $state, $context) {
                        // Set default value for the first instance only
                        if ($context->index === 0) {
                            return $get('../../contact_number');
                        }
                        return null; // No default for other instances
                    }),


I have something like this, hope it helps:
Repeater::make('features')
                                ->hint('Add up to 3 features')
                                ->hiddenLabel()
                                ->schema([
                                    TextInput::make('heading')
                                        ->required()
                                        ->default(''),
                                    Textarea::make('content')
                                        ->required()
                                        ->default(''),
                                ])
                                ->maxItems(3)
                                ->afterStateHydrated(function ($set, $operation) {
                                    $defaults = [
                                        [
                                            'heading' => 'heading1',
                                            'content' => 'content1',
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            'heading' => 'heading2',
                                            'content' => 'content2',
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            'heading' => 'heading3',
                                            'content' => 'content3',
                                        ],
                                    ];
    
                                    //check if component is instanceof createRecord
                                    if ($operation == 'create') {
                                        $set('features', $defaults);
                                    }
                                }),


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
